# Let $G_i=\{\sigma\in S_n:\sigma(i)=i\}$. Describe the cosets of $\frac{S_n}{G_n}$. How many cosets are there? List them.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group of permutations of ${1,2,..., n}$ and let $i = {1,2,...,n}$.

Let $G_i = \{ \sigma \in S_n : \sigma(i) =i\}$. Describe the cosets of $\frac{S_n}{G_n}$. How many cosets are there? List them.

Edit : I could prove that $G_i$ is a subgroup, even a normal subgroup which was also given in the problem.

$$\text{Let,} \alpha , \beta \in G_i \\
      \implies \alpha(i) = i , \beta (i) = i \\
       \implies \beta^{-1}(i) = i   \\
       \implies \alpha (\beta^{-1}(i)) = \alpha(i) = i \\
       \implies \alpha \beta^{-1} \in G_i  $$
Therefore $G_i$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Also for any $f \in S_n$ and any $\sigma \in G_i$

$$ f \sigma (f^{-1}(i)) = f(f^{-1})(i) = i \\ 
\implies f \sigma f^{-1} \in G_i   $$

Therefore, $G_i$ is normal in $S_n$.

But for the rest of it I couldn't go any further.

Any suggestions/hint where to start, I'm totally lost.

Comment: There are $(n-1)!$ bijections which fix $n$

Comment: Yes I understand. So there will be $n$ different cosets of $G_i$ ? But what will they look like? I am asked to give a formal descriptive answer and I'm really being unable to do so. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Yes, one answer below explained it

Comment: The cosets are copies of $S_{n-1}\cong G_n$. For each element $a\in S_{n}$ there exists $aS_{n-1}\in S_n/S_{n-1}$. Two cosets $[a],[a']$ are the same iff $a{a'}^{-1}\in S_{n-1}$, meaning $a(n)=a'(n)$. There are $n$ choices for the image of $n$ in $S_n$

Comment: By the way, $G_i$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_n$. For $n \ge 5$, the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we think of cosets, we think of an equivalence relation. What is an equivalence relation? It is a way of grouping together objects that we deem as equivalent. Suppose I ask you the following question, how many different groups of triangles are there such that two triangles having the same angles are grouped together? You'd pick a triangle out of each group and there would be as many triangles as there are 3-multisets $\lbrace a,b,\pi-a-b\rbrace$ with all elements positive.

The question you want the answer to is this. How many different types of permutations are there if I put two permutations with the same value for $n$ together? You'd put the permutations with $\sigma(n)=1$ in a group, ones with $\sigma(n)=2$ in a different group and so on. How many groups are there?

Look at the set of $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $\sigma(n)=i$ for a fixed $i$, with $1\leq i \leq n$. Call these sets $H_i$. How does one go from $G_n$ to a set $H_i$?

Also, can you see that $\cup H_i=S_n$? Every permutation must take the element $n$ somewhere and these sets account for all of them. What are the cardinalities of these $H_i$? What is $H_i \cap H_j$?

Comment: Yes @Umesh I understand. For a particular $n$, all the permutations that doesn't fix $n$ have $n-1$ choices beginning from $1$ to $n-1$.

Comment: Isn't $G_n$ = $H_n$?

Comment: Yes, they're the same.

Comment: If representative of $H_i$ is $\sigma_i$ such that $\sigma_i(n) = i$ then I think $\sigma_i G_n = H_i$. Am I correct?

Comment: Cardinalities of each $H_i$ is $(n-1)!$ as there are that many choices for a permutation fixing a particular element.

Comment: Being careful while using the word 'fix'. It is generally used when $\sigma(n)=n$. The permutations in $H_i$ fix the value of $n$ to be $i$, even though they don't 'fix' $n$.

Comment: $H_i \cap H_j = \phi $ as no permutation can simultaneously send $n$ to $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Yes I'll be more careful using it. Okay can you tell me that what should I write the representative of each $H_i$, can it be $\sigma_i$ as I defined it previously? Also if I'm asked to state and proof a property that each element of the same coset have in common, how should I go about writing it?

Comment: Look at the following analogy and it will clear everything up. In the triangle case, if I asked you to pick a representative for the class $(45,45,90)$, what triangle would you pick? You'd pick any triangle, right? Same way when you're asked for a representative in $H_i$, which one should you pick?

Comment: There is nothing special about $(n i)$ that the other answer picked. You could've picked literally any element in $H_i$. All are valid candidates.

Comment: Do you think that "the cosets of $\frac{S_n}{G_n}$" written in the question is a typo, because we all are finding the cosets of $G_n$?

Answer (score 3):

First of all notice that $|G_n| = (n-1)!$. From Lagrange we get that $\left|\frac{S_n}{G_n}\right|= \frac{|S_n|}{|G_n|} = n$ so there are $n$ cosets. Now consider for each $k=1,\dots, n$ the permutation $\sigma_k = (kn)$. Next show that $\sigma_k G_n \cap \sigma_l G_n = \emptyset$ for $k\neq l$ which forces the set $\{\sigma_k G_n: k=1,\dots, n\}$ to be the set of cosets of $G_n$.

Comment: By $(1 k)$ are you meaning the 2-cycle $(1 k)$ that sends $1$ to $k$ and $k$ to $1$?

Comment: @Itachi Yes exactly.

Comment: Okay. But I'm really confused, why $\sigma_k$? I mean if we are finding cosets of $G_n$ where $n$ is fixed shouldn't we find those permutations who doesn't fix $n$ ?

Comment: @Itachi You're right it's a typo. Fixed!

Comment: What is $H$? I don't see it mentioned in the OP, nor prior in your answer.

Comment: @CAB You are right it was a typo. I meant $G_n$.